# solution for sending/receiving emails from my own domain

Tags: email, security, mail-server

since I am not into mailing yet - I wanted to ask the community. I got domains which are linking on several vServer / dedicated Server. I use those server in general for Webapplications & Hosting (LAMP).

I already figured out that it's quite easy to receive eMails on domains which are forwarding on one of my server - with an simple redirect - like example@domain.org gets forwarded from my server to myuser@myfreeemailprovider.com

But now I want to start sending eMails from example@domain.org out into the great evil internet. So is there a easy way to do it ? Like using the Mailserver of my free email-provider but with "From : myuser@myfreeemailprovider.com" ? Or is the only real solution an own mailserver ?

If a own mailserver is the only solution here - is there anything I have to take care about in fact of security if I roll one out of my production Webserver Webserver ?

I appriciate any help and thoughts.

btw. ... I am only using Linux Server so no Microsoft stuff.

Comment: There are dozens of mail server solutions that exists.  Which one have you chosen to use?

Comment: @Ramhound I've chosen none yet. I wanted to know if there is another solution besides using a Mailserver and if not what do I have to take care of (in terms of security) if I deploy a mailserver (like qmail) on one of my servere where I already running LAMP for example

Comment: You might want to revise your question so its crystal clear what your looking for.  The only way to send email on your own domain is to either pay for an email server or setup your own email server.  There might be free alternatives, which you can find yourself, if thats what you want.

Comment: someone just threw in programs like "ssmtp" or "nullmailer" - you have any ideas if they could solve this problem too ?

Well otherwise I might go for rolling out my first own mailserver otherwise ...

Answer (score 0):

Give [Windows Live Admin](https://domains.live.com/) a try with their free custom domains email service. You simply setup an account using a Microsoft account and then you can create custom emails for your domain. You have to perform some verification steps such as modifying DNS records but once that is done you can send and receive from your custom domain.

Email clients like Gmail can be setup to use POP and IMAP to send a receive email via your custom email.

Comment: The free custom domain service Microsoft offered is no longer offered currently.  He won't be able to setup a new domain up.

Comment: @Ramhound oh wow, I did not know that. I just setup my email a couple months ago there. Guess I got lucky getting in before they shut it down!

Comment: **It was well covered** by a variety of technical news websites.  It was also announce ahead of time which was also covered.

Comment: @Ramhound I must live under a rock then.

Answer (score 0):

When sending an email you can specify whatever originating domain you want.
You can use any email provider and modify the "From:" field when sending your email to the server.

For example, I send emails with PHP mail() function using my ISP's SMTP server, only passing 'me@mydomain.com' as the 'From' argument to the mail() function.

On the receiving side, it looks like the email really comes from mydomain.com.

I don't know if it's best practice but it works like a charm so far.